# have a different id and name for a form select option using the rails helper tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do you have a different id and name for a form select option using the rails helper tag?

```
 select_tag "test['data']",options_from_collection_for_select(@test_data, 'id', 'name', @test_data.id),:prompt => @test_data.name
```

In the above example, the name needs to be whatever is returned by test['data'] which is happening.
 But I want to name the id something else. How do i do that?

I want the id to be some fixed value for all. But the name should be based on test['data']

```
select id="my_test" name="whatever test['data'] is returned"
```

I need the id for some javascript manipulation. For eg. auto submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you want for the id. You can specify any method that members of `@test_data` have.

For example

```
 options_from_collection_for_select(@test_data, 'email', 'name')
```

Will return the `email` from the members inside `@test_data`.

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@test_data, 'my_method', 'name')
```

Will return whatever `my_method` returns for each of the collections' members.

It all depends on what you have stored in your `@test_data` collection and to what methods these members respond.

More info here

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select

**Update**

```
select_tag "test['data']",options_from_collection_for_select(@test_data, 'id', 'name', @test_data.id),:prompt => @test_data.name, :id => 'my_id'
```

Comment: I want the id to return some fixed value. see my edit to my question. I need the id for some javascript manipulation. For eg. auto submit

Comment: The `options_from_collection_for_select` method retrieves the names and values for the options. **Not** for the select itself. To see how you set the id for the select tag see my updated answer.